# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError under tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, linker, java-native-interface

I have a java class (eval.java) that invokes a native method in an so file (libmodel.so). I can use System.loadLibrary() to load the libmodel.so without any error (-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib), and the native method initModel() works fine.

However, when I deploy it as a web service (tomcat 6.0.26 + axis2 1.5.1 + eclipse Java EE helios) to call the native method, I got the following error (the first line means the .so was successfully loaded):

```
Load library successfully
[ERROR] com.model.modelJNI.initModel()V
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.model.modelJNI.initModel()V
    at com.model.modelJNI.initModel(Native Method)
    at com.model.model.initModel(model.java:13)
    at com.webservice.run(EvalVita.java:763)
    ... 25 more
```

Below is the body of Eval.java

```
import com.model.*;

public class Eval {
  static void loadModel() {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("model");
        System.out.println("Load library successfully");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load." + e);
    }
  }
  public void run() {
    loadModel();
    model.initModel();
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything here?  Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Have you definitely specified the same java.library.path when running under Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat does has the library path.  /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/lib/i386/server: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/lib/i386: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_01/jre/../lib/i386: /usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386: /lib: /usr/lib

Comment: I assume this is tomcat classpath, but do you pass -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib argument to JVM you are running tomcat on?

Comment: @Georgy Yes, I did but still got the same error message. Here is the full arguments to JVM I'm running tomcat on: -Dcatalina.base="/homes/mouthu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="/homes/mouthu/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.26" -Dwtp.deploy="/homes/mouthu/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="/homes/mouthu/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/endorsed" -Djava.library.path="/usr/lib"

Comment: Can you clarify two things: 1. model.initModel(); where model comes from? and 2. what is in model.initModel(); (I assume it is a native method, so, can you show the C/C++/whatever method)?

Comment: 1. the model comes from a jar file (import com.model.*), which contains JNI classes generated using SWIG. 2. It's C++: 
<pre>
#include <HEC.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

string path="/tmp/model.xml";

HEC *hec_obj;

void initModel() {
    hec_obj = new HEC(path);

    if (!hec_obj) {
        cout << "[ERROR] Cannot instantiate HEC objects.";
    }
}
</pre>
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that the *library* was loaded successfully, but the individual *function* needed by JNI could not be found (or was not declared properly).  Here is an example of what your C code should look like:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_model_modelJNI
 * Method:    initModel
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_model_modelJNI_initModel
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass jclazz)
{
  // etc.
}
```

I've never used Swig before, so I'm not sure how it works with JNI.  But you might want to try using [javah](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javah.html) and seeing what it outputs, to compare.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I checked the wrapper code generated by SWIG and it did have the similar thing you posted:

<pre>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_model_modelJNI_initModel(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  initModel();
}
</pre>

I was just wondering why it works for standalone app but not for deployed webservice.

Comment: Is it possible that the `libmodel.so` file being loaded from the Tomcat JVM is not the same as the one loaded from your standalone test?